# reading a .bmp file c ++, wrong values?

Tags: c++, bmp

Here's my code for reading from a bmp file(using windows.h). It reads the correct values from BITMAPFILEHEADER, yet all the values read from BITMAPINFOHEADER are 40(28 in hex).
what is wrong?

```
ifstream file("d3.bmp",ios::binary);
BITMAPFILEHEADER fheader;
BITMAPINFOHEADER aImg;

ofstream fileOut("newfile5.txt",ios::app);

file.read((char*)&fheader.bfType, sizeof(WORD));
fileOut<<std::hex<<fheader.bfType<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&fheader.bfSize, sizeof(DWORD));
fileOut<<fheader.bfSize<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&fheader.bfReserved1, sizeof(WORD));
fileOut<<fheader.bfReserved1<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&fheader.bfReserved2, sizeof(WORD));
fileOut<<fheader.bfReserved2<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&fheader.bfOffBits, sizeof(DWORD));
fileOut<<fheader.bfOffBits<<"\n";


file.read((char*)&aImg.biSize,sizeof(DWORD));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&aImg.biWidth, sizeof(LONG));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&aImg.biHeight, sizeof(LONG));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&aImg.biPlanes, sizeof(WORD));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&aImg.biBitCount, sizeof(WORD));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&aImg.biCompression, sizeof(DWORD));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&aImg.biSizeImage, sizeof(DWORD));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&aImg.biXPelsPerMeter, sizeof(LONG));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&aImg.biYPelsPerMeter, sizeof(LONG));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&aImg.biClrUsed, sizeof(DWORD));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n";
file.read((char*)&aImg.biClrImportant, sizeof(DWORD));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n";
```

Comment: Just some advice : instead of sizeof(LONG) use sizeof(&aImg.biXPelsPerMeter) i.e. not hard-coding the size , let the compiler work for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that the values that are being *read* are correct, it's just that you always *output* the same byte over and over again:

```
file.read((char*)&aImg.biSize,sizeof(DWORD));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n"; //ok, biSize
file.read((char*)&aImg.biWidth, sizeof(LONG));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n"; //wait, biSize again?
file.read((char*)&aImg.biHeight, sizeof(LONG));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n"; //well somehow I'm getting suspicious
file.read((char*)&aImg.biPlanes, sizeof(WORD));
fileOut<<aImg.biSize<<"\n"; //...
file.read((char*)&aImg.biBitCount, sizeof(WORD));
...
```